# What was the colour of the shoes used by the Apollo astronauts in moon landing?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, astronauts, apollo-11, moonwalking

The pictures from Apollo landing despite being in high resolution, does not reveal the right colour of the shoes used by the astronauts during the EVA on the moon. An example  - [Buzz Aldrin picture from Apollo 11](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Aldrin_Apollo_11_original.jpg)

[image: Buzz Aldrin from Apollo 11]

But a shot from the movie First Man shows in clear detail the colour of the shoes being greenish-bluish.
[image: First Man movie shot]

So, it makes one curious to know whether the depiction of the astronaut's shoes was accurate in the movie. If true, then what is the material that gives this colour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shoes of the [A7L suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo/Skylab_A7L) were white with partly-blue "lunar boots" worn over them, but soon were covered in grey-ish dust once on the moon. Have a look at this [image on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_11_space_suit.jpg):

[image: A7L suit]

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what is the material that gave the lunar boots that blue colour tip?

Comment: @karthikeyan: The material is [silicone rubber](http://heroicrelics.org/info/suits/a7l-lunar-overboot.html), but I don't know whether the blue is its "natural" color or whether it's dyed.

Comment: @DarkDust Silicones are whitish and translucent unless dyed.